# Redirect user to login page with Symfony 4 for anonymous user

Tags: php, symfony, security

When I modified the access_control in security.yaml page to ensure that some folder are protected like admin

> ```
> access_control:
>     - { path: '^/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
> ```

but sometimes, I need to check if the user access can access on some protected content using :

> ```
>     if (false === $authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_FOURNISSEUR')) {
>         throw new AccessDeniedException("Impossible d'accéder à cette page !");
>     }
> ```

or :

> ```
>     $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', null, "Impossible d'accéder à cette page !");
> ```

In  that both case, I'm not redirected to the login page but I have an error page. How can I modify that behaviour (and if the user log in, redirect him to the page he asked for)

Comment: You should be redirected to login by default, when not logged in. If you want ROLE_ADMIN to automatically have the ROLE_FOURNISSEUR role, too, look into role_hirarchy

Comment: you're right. Tks